# Reduce import database duration

Tags: mysql, database, import, temp

I have a database with a number of tables and data. Inorder to import the database, the query

```
LOAD DATA INFILE <file_name> INTO TABLE <table_name>;
```

for each table is used. The database is imported via temporary table and since the database contains large data, it takes a long time. When the data increases, the import takes infinite time delay. How can I solve this issue?

```
public void updateDeviceTables(Connection server) throws SQLException
{

    final Connection DestConn = server;
    try 
    {

        PreparedStatement psInsert;
        final PreparedStatement psTrapDest = DestConn
            .prepareStatement("select * from  TEMP_TABLE_NAME where PRIMARY_KEYID=? ");
            psTrapDest.setInt(1, OldID);
            final ResultSet rsTrapDest = psTrapDest.executeQuery();

            while (rsTrapDest.next()) {
                psInsert = DestConn.prepareStatement(SQLQueries.INSERT_TABLE_DETAILS);

                psInsert.setInt(1, NewID);
                psInsert.setObject(2, rsTrapDest.getObject("Column2"));
                psInsert.setObject(3, rsTrapDest.getObject("Column3"));

                psInsert.executeUpdate();
                psInsert.close();
                psInsert = null;
            }
            rsTrapDest.close();
     }
     catch (final Exception e) 
     {

     }

}
```

This is the sample code I use to update the tables after the datas are imported to temporary tables. The same procedure repeated for all the tables in the database (17 tables) The debugging stuck in  **executeUpdate()**.

Comment: Does your temporary table have any indexes defined? If so you should disable them and the load should be very quick.

Comment: @Ilion The indexes are generated automatically and are primary keys. it is not possible to disable them

Comment: Do you not have permissions to drop the indexes on the temp table? Ideally you would ensure uniqueness in the data file, import into the temp table without indexes, and then copy from the temp table to the permanent table. The copy should be faster than loading in directly and will apply indexing at that time.

Comment: How do you mean it is not possible to disable them? Definitely, import data in table without indexes will be significantly faster. Remove your primary key constraint with `ALTER TABLE table_name DROP PRIMARY KEY;`, and then try to import data.